# Do I need Windows Server in any network?

Tags: sql-server, networking, windows-server

For exp. I have one program work on one network Which is composed of two computers.
The program uses SQLServer.
Do I need Win Server in this network?

(Excuse me. I understand a little English...)

Comment: @sharptooth that wasn't the question.

Answer (score 2):

For two users you would probably be able to run SQL Server Express Edition (Which is Free) on one of the computers.

Assuming your both your computers are windows machines and not something else then your application can run on both machines.

1 instance of your application can access the local sql server.  Whilst the 2nd instance can access the server on other PC.

There is a list of hardware and software requirements [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#SEx64) (at least for SQL Server 2008).

Comment: I used from SQL Server Standard Edition! This edition works without Win Server?!

Comment: See Edit...SQL Server Standard Edition seems a bit pricey for a 2 user application.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you do not need one, SQLServer supports normal OS like Windows XP, Vista ... so accessing the server form the other Computer should be possible, for Example by providing the host URL in the Connectionstring in your application. if im wrong ill appreciate some explanation instead of downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Your example is SQL Server. Some versions of SQL Server require a server-class OS. Some do not. You'd need to reference the SQL Server requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If it's microsoft SQL Server then yes you will. However you can virtualise this like other OS's. However you will need a windows server. If it's a Sybase SQL server then no.